# HLSL REPL? Unit tests?

Tags: hlsl, compute-shader, directx-12

I'm about to modify an mathematical algorithm and my ptsd is being seriously triggered.

No repl. No unit tests. No ability no mock input data. No asserts. How do game devs stay sane?

Is just recompiling the shader in PIX the best work flow available?

I think I'll just port the shader to c++ until I understand how to modify the algorithm correctly. (Maybe it's worth getting the [Cling repl](https://github.com/root-project/cling) going)